# How to change the dimension of a table to fit a fraction?

Tags: tables

It's a stupid question but I'm not able to solve it.
In this very simple example i would like to understand how to change the dimension of the table in order to have a better look expecially for the last element \frac{5x}{3}. I tried with displaystyle but it not worked. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline
f(x) & x^2 & x^4+2 & 15 & \frac{5x}{3} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: your first math expression is just `$\displaystyle{{$`  so has two mismatched `{`the syntax would be `$\displaystyle f(x)$`  but it only applies to that expression.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code, both to make it compilable and to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 8):

with use of `makecell` package you can define gapes above and below cell content. for example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, makecell}  % <---
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\setcellgapes{5pt}            % <--- 
\begin{document}

\[
\makegapedcells               % <---
\begin{array}{|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\hline
f(x) & x^2 & x^4+2 & 15 & \frac{5x}{3} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Adding `\mathstrut` directives in both the numerator and the denominator of the final fraction may achieve your formatting objective(s).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline
f(x) & x^2 & x^4+2 & 15 & \frac{5x\mathstrut}{3\mathstrut} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with `cellspace`; which defines *minimal* vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns prefixed with the letter `S`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$\displaystyle}Sc<{$}}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{|*{5}{C|}}
    \hline
    x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \hline
    f(x) & x^2 & x^4+2 & 15 & \frac{5x}{3} \\
    \hline
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have added, instead, only the package `mathtools` and the command `\dfrac+\strut`. It works fine an I have used few code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, mathtools}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{|C|C|C|C|C|}
\hline
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline
f(x) & x^2 & x^4+2 & 15 & \dfrac{\strut 5x}{\strut 3} \\ 
\hline
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```